# GDB binds the symbol in shared library automatically

Tags: c, linker, gdb, shared-libraries

I was trying to learn how the shared library works. So I created the simple program;

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
        printf("hi");
}
```

using following command:

```
 gcc -g -Wl,-z,norelro test.cc -o test
```

to specify No Relro. However, when the printf@plt gets called,

```
0x5555555544e0 <printf@plt> jmpq   *0x20055a(%rip)        # 0x555555754a40
```

from here, GDB jumps right into the libc, rather than running the resolving procedure as if the entry in GDB is already filled. I put bp on printf so I am pretty sure that it was the first time that printf has called.

How to make gdb stop doing this so that I can observe the binding process?

Comment: are you working with `C` or `C++`  They are very different languages.  The posted code is for `C`.   What 'binding' are you speaking of?  Note: `gdb` does not 'bind`

Comment: the posted code,, written in `C++` would look like: `#include <iostream> namespace std; int main( void ) { cout "hi" << endl; }`

Comment: it is the `link` step that adds the sharable library and resolves all the addresses, not `gdb`

Comment: Pretty sure linked shared libraries are loaded on startup not when they're first used

Comment: Can you edit your question to show a log of your gdb session?